# WPF Background Worker UI not responding as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a class that subscribe a few methods which I then execute in a background worker. (Not sure if I should execute in background worker or not) The class trigger some events, and I want to display information regarding these events on the screen. 
The flow is as follows:
After I call the `AcceptCash` method it waits for the user to do some things. When the operation is done and all cash is received and change needs to be dispensed the `StartDispense` event is executed and that works. My busy screen comes up as expected.

If the `IncompleteDispense` event is called, I want a "Busy" screen to be displayed telling the user of the incomplete dispense, and wait for a few seconds. The problem is that the `ProcessComplete` event is fired almost immediately after the incomplete dispense event. 
This event should wait for the incomplete dispense screen to go away, and then continue. But my wait part seems to lock the incomplete dispense thread and the incomplete message is not always displayed, displayed only as a quick flash, or not at all.

This is a simple example of my code

```
private void continuePaymentProcess()
{
    paymentController.IncompleteDispense += PaymentModule_IncompleteDispense;
    paymentController.TransactionFinalised += PaymentModule_ProcessComplete;
    paymentController.StartDispense += PaymentController_StartDispense;

//Is this necessary??
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        paymentController.AcceptCash(items.Values.Sum(x => x.ItemAmount));
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void PaymentController_StartDispense(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ShowBusy();
}

private void PaymentModule_IncompleteDispense(decimal amount, CashItem[] cashItems)
{
    DispenseMessage = true;

    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        if (amountToDispense > 0)       //This will only happen if a cashin was cancelled
            paymentController.PrintVoucher(amountToDispense, "123123");
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);   //I think this is where my problem is
        BlankPage.MainInstance.HideBusy();
        DispenseMessage = false;
    };
    ShowBusy("INCOMPLETE DISPENSE!!!", $"Only {amount:c} was dispensed. A voucher for the rest of the money will be issued", false);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void PaymentModule_ProcessComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        while (DispenseMessage) 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        ShowBusy();
        foreach (var item in payItems)
        {
            try
            {
                ... Process some items
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
    {
        HideBusy();
        ShowWelcomePage();
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

This is the ShowBusy and HideBusy methods

```
public void ShowBusy(string Message = "Busy processing your request", string subMessage = "Please wait...", bool showProgress = true)
{
    this.Dispatcher.InvokeIfRequired(() => 
    {
        loadingPanel.ShowProgress = showProgress;
        loadingPanel.Message = Message;
        loadingPanel.SubMessage = subMessage;
        PanelLoading = true;
        Task.Delay(1000);
    }, true, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
}

public void HideBusy()
{
    this.Dispatcher.InvokeIfRequired(() =>
    {
        PanelLoading = false;
    }, true, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
}
```

I've made the priority as high as I could, but it does not help.

This is the InvokeIfRequired extension

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Dispatcher dispatcher, Action action, bool useInvoke = false, DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle)
{
    if (dispatcher == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        if (useInvoke)
            dispatcher.Invoke(action, priority);
        else
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, priority);
        return;
    }
    action();
}
```

Comment: You don't need BGW or Invoke. There are dozens of duplicate questions since 2012 that explain why you shouldn't use them and how *simple* it is to use Task.Run and `async/await`. Simply `updateTheUI(); await Task.Run(()=>DoStuffInTheBackground()); resetTheUI();`. No Invoke, no dispatchers

Comment: Yep. But also. Don't burn a thread. thread.sleep is almost always a bad idea in a desktop app. Can the user even do anything whilst that stuff is processing? Maybe they're stood looking at a busy spinner until it's finished and multi threading is not really adding so much. Maybe parallel foreach would be a better solution.

Comment: The user is not suppose to be able to do anything while this is processing. I've changed a lot of code to async await and it seems to work now. Thanks